# Question on my proof for $\lim_{x\to 0}\cos(x)=1$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Prove $$\lim_{x\to 0}\cos(x)=1$$

Proof: Fix $\epsilon>0$. Let $\delta=min\{\epsilon,\frac{\pi}{2}\}$. If $0$ <$\lvert{x-0}\lvert$< $\delta,$ we have $0$ <$\lvert{x}\lvert$< $\delta$ and $0$ <$\lvert{x}\lvert$< $\frac{\pi}{2}.$ Observe the latter, $$0 <\lvert{x}\lvert< \frac{\pi}{2}$$ $$\implies 0 < 1-\frac{sin(x)}{x}< 1-cos(x)$$ $$\implies 1-cos(x)=2sin^2(\frac{x}{2})$$  $$\implies 2\times\lvert{sin(\frac{x}{2}})\lvert\times\lvert{sin(\frac{x}{2}})\lvert$$ $$\le 2\times\lvert{\frac{x}{2}}\lvert\times1$$ $$=\lvert{x}\lvert<\epsilon.$$ 
Since $\epsilon>0$ was arbitrary, by definition of limit, $$\lim_{x\to 0}\cos(x)=1.$$

Do I have to mention $\frac{\pi}{2}$ in the minimum?

Comment: The "need" for $\pi/2$ isn't so clear. It works with, and works without. For the case were you don't use $\pi/2$ use the left and right sided limits, and in this case you can essentially "ignore" all the terms of $x$ until you're between $0$ and $\pi/2$ or $0$ and $-\pi/2$ depending on whether you are looking at the left or right sided limit case.

Comment: You have used the inequality $|\sin x|\leq |x|$ which is true for all $x$ and not specifically for all $x$ with $|x|\leq \pi/2$. So there is no need to use it in the minimum. Choosing $\delta=\epsilon$ works without any issues. Another approach is use to use the limit $\lim_{x\to 0}\sin x=0$ (a consequence of $|\sin x|\leq |x|$) and the identity $\cos x=\sqrt{1-\sin^{2}x}$ which is valid is a neighborhood of $0$.